# Erro ao Buscar Serial Postgresql

Tags: c#, postgresql

Utilizando: c#, windows forms, postgresql

Estou tendo dificuldade para montar uma rotina 
que grava dados em uma tabela e recupera o id 
gravado(serial / sequence) e atualiza o log em outra
tabela.

O pior de tudo é que tudo funciona Debugando, mas se
manda rodar direto da o exception:

> ERRO: 55000: valor atual da sequência "banco_id_seq"  ainda não foi
>   definido nesta sessão.

Esse erro acontece ao passar pela rotina "Buscar_ID".

Não sei o que pode estar acontecendo, ou como contornar
isso, pois como uma coisa pode funcionar debugando e
executando não funcionar ?

segue abaixo trecos dos codigos:

Gravar

```
    protected override void Gravar_Registro()
    {
        using (base.cn = Dados.getInstancia().getConexao())
        {
            cn.Open();
            NpgsqlTransaction tr = cn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);

            try
            {
                NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = cn;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                cmd.CommandText = DAL.Banco.Insert();

                Tela_Para_Banco(cmd);

                cmd.Transaction = tr;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                Log_Sistema(tr, Rotina.Usuario_Login, this.Text, cmd);

                tr.Commit();
                cn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                tr.Rollback();
                throw new Exception("Servidor SQL Erro: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        beCodigo.IdTable = Buscar_ID("banco").ToString();
        beCodigo.Text = beCodigo.IdTable;
    }
```

LOG

```
    private void Log_Sistema(NpgsqlTransaction tr, string strUsuario, string strTela, NpgsqlCommand cCommand)
    {
        using (NpgsqlConnection cn = Dados.getInstancia().getConexao())
        {
            try
            {
                cn.Open();

                NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = cn;

                cmd.CommandText = "insert into log (data, usuario, tela, sql) values (current_timestamp, @usuario, @tela, @sql);"; 

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usuario", strUsuario);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tela", strTela);

                string tTexto = "";

                for (int i = 0; i < cCommand.CommandText.Length - 1; i++)
                {
                    tTexto = tTexto + cCommand.CommandText.Substring(i, 1);

                    if ((cCommand.CommandText.Substring(i, 1) == ",") || (cCommand.CommandText.Substring(i, 1) == " ") || (cCommand.CommandText.Substring(i, 1) == ")"))
                    {
                        foreach (NpgsqlParameter p in cCommand.Parameters)
                        {
                            string sParametro_Nome = p.ParameterName.ToString();
                            string sParametro_Valor = Rotina.ReturnEmptyIfNull(p.Value);

                            if (tTexto.IndexOf(sParametro_Nome) > 0)
                                if (tTexto.Substring(tTexto.IndexOf(sParametro_Nome), (tTexto.Length - 1) - tTexto.IndexOf(sParametro_Nome)) == sParametro_Nome)
                                {
                                    tTexto = tTexto.Replace(sParametro_Nome, sParametro_Valor);
                                    break;
                                }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (tTexto != "")
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sql", tTexto);

                cmd.Transaction = tr;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Servidor SQL Erro: " + ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                cn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Recupera ID

```
    public static string Buscar_ID(string sTabela)                                                                                 
    {                                                                                                                              
        using (NpgsqlConnection cn = Dados.getInstancia().getConexao())                                                            
        {                                                                                                                          
            try                                                                                                                    
            {                                                                                                                      
                cn.Open();                                                                                                         
                NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand((String.Format("select currval('public.{0}_id_seq');", sTabela)), cn);
                NpgsqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();                                                                         

                dr.Read();                                                                                                         

                if (dr.HasRows)                                                                                                    
                    if (dr.IsDBNull(0))                                                                                            
                        return "1";                                                                                                
                    else                                                                                                           
                        return dr[0].ToString();                                                                                   
                else                                                                                                               
                    return "1";                                                                                                    
            }                                                                                                                      
            catch (Exception ex)                                                                                                   
            {                                                                                                                      
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);                                                                                   
            }                                                                                                                      
            finally                                                                                                                
            {                                                                                                                      
                cn.Close();                                                                                                        
            }                                                                                                                      
        }                                                                                                                          
    }
```

Comment: É comum algo funcionar no debug e não funcionar no release, por incrível que pareça. No debug mode, o ambiente de execução é mais relaxado e por isso menos erros são gerados. Por isso que em problemas que ocorre apenas no release se usa um just in time debugger junto com arquivos símbolos (PDB no caso de .Net), permitindo debugar aplicações release em um ambiente de execução real.

Answer (score 1):

Uma sugestão de recuperar o id da sequence inserido é utilizar a clausula [RETURNING](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-insert.html) no insert, também é preciso trocar [ExecuteNonQuery()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) que retorna o número de linhas afetadas por [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) qu segundo a documentação retornar somente a primeira coluna e linha de uma consulta.

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO log (data, usuario, tela, sql)
VALUES (current_timestamp, @usuario, @tela, @sql) RETURNING NOME_DO_CAMPO_SERIAL;"

....
ultimo_id = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: Eu entendo e até analisei essa opção de retonar o id pelo insert, porém o que me incomoda é o fato de não funionar como se é esperado e programado, pois o que me preocupa é la na frente quando estiver construindo forms mestre-detalhe descobrir que a implementação tem falhas. Interessante é que ao comentar a rotina do log, o erro desaparece passando a funcionar tanto em debug como em release, mas o que pode estar acontecendo nesse meio tempo na rotina de log que "desanda" o restante, parece um time-out entre o commit e o banco....ou estou ficando louco mesmo....!!!

Answer (score 0):

A função `CURRVAL` retorna o último valor da sequencia gerada na sua sessão. Este erro ocorre ao chamar a função `CURRVALS` sem antes ter avançado a `SEQUENCE`.

No seu caso, o problema é que o método `Buscar_ID` está sendo chamado fora da transação. Tente assim:

Gravar_Registro:

```c#
protected override void Gravar_Registro()
{
     using (base.cn = Dados.getInstancia().getConexao())
     {
         cn.Open();
         NpgsqlTransaction tr = cn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);

         try
         {
             NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand();
             cmd.Connection = cn;
             cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

             cmd.CommandText = DAL.Banco.Insert();

             Tela_Para_Banco(cmd);

             cmd.Transaction = tr;
             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

             Log_Sistema(tr, Rotina.Usuario_Login, this.Text, cmd);

             // Chamado antes de terminar a transação
             beCodigo.IdTable = Buscar_ID("banco", cn).ToString();

             tr.Commit();
             cn.Close();
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             tr.Rollback();
             throw new Exception("Servidor SQL Erro: " + ex.Message);
         }
     }

     beCodigo.Text = beCodigo.IdTable;
}
```

Buscar_ID:

```c#
private static string Buscar_ID(string sTabela, NpgsqlConnection conexao)                                                                                 
{                                                                                                                              
    var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand((String.Format("select currval('public.{0}_id_seq');", sTabela)), conexao);
    using(var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {    
       if (dr.Read())                                                                                                    
           if (dr.IsDBNull(0))                                                                                            
               return "1";                                                                                                
           else                                                                                                           
               return dr[0].ToString();                                                                                   
       else                                                                                                               
           return "1";                                                                                                    
   }
}
```